# $g(x) = \sin(2nx) + \sin(4nx) - \sin(6nx)$ Find an expression for the largest root of the equation $g(x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Let $$f(x) = P\sin(x) + Q\sin(2x) + R\sin(3x)$$
>
> (a) Show that if $Q^2<4R(P-R)$, then the only values of $x$ for which
> $f(x)=0$ are given by $x=m\pi$, where $m$ is an integer.
>
> (b) Now let $$g(x) = \sin(2nx) + \sin(4nx) - \sin(6nx)$$,
>
> where $n$ is a positive integer and $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Find an
> expression for the largest root of the equation $g(x)=0$,
> distinguishing between the cases where $n$ is even and $n$ is odd.

Workings:

(a) The first part is simple enough. $$f(x) = P\sin(x) + Q(2\sin(x)\cos(x)) + R\sin(x)(4\cos^2(x) -1) $$

$$\iff \sin(x) (P+2Q\cos(x)+R(4\cos^2(x)-1))$$

$$\therefore \sin(x)(4R\cos^2(x)+2Q\cos(x)+P-R)$$

So, when $\Delta = 4Q^2-4(4R)(P-R) <0 \iff Q^2<4R(P-R)$. So, if this inequality holds. The quadratic in $\cos(x)$ has no real solutions and hence $f(x) = 0$ iff $\sin(x) = 0 \iff x=m\pi$

(b) The second part is where I am struggling. We let $P=Q = 1$ and $R=-1$ to apply the results in the first part.

$$g(x) = \sin(2nx)(-4\cos^2(2nx)+2\cos(2nx)+2) $$
$$\iff 2\sin(2nx)(-2\cos^2(2nx)+\cos(2nx)+1)$$

$$\therefore g(x) = 2\sin(2nx)(2\cos(2nx)+1)(-\cos(2nx)+1)$$

Hence $g(x) = 0 \iff 2\sin(2nx)(2\cos(2nx)+1)(-\cos(2nx)+1)=0$

$2\sin(2nx) = 0 \iff 2nx=\pi m \iff x = \frac{\pi m}{2n} $

$\cos(2nx) = -\frac{1}{2} \iff 2nx = \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + (2m+1) \pi \iff x = \pm \frac{\pi}{6nx} + \frac{(2m+1) \pi}{2n}$

$\cos(2nx) = 1 \iff 2nx = 2\pi m \iff x = \frac{2\pi m}{2n}$

We now have 3 general solutions for the roots of $g(x)$, I am struggling to compare them and come up with an expression that will represent the largest root out of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got
$$x=\frac{m}{2n}\pi,\frac{3m+2}{3n}\pi,\frac{3m+1}{3n}\pi,\frac{m}{n}\pi$$
I think that these are correct.

Since $0\lt x\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, we have
$$0\lt \frac{m}{2n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt n$$
$$0\lt \frac{3m+2}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac{2}{3}\lt m\lt\dfrac{3n-4}{6}$$
$$0\lt \frac{3m+1}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac 13\lt m\lt\dfrac{3n-2}{6}$$
$$0\lt \frac{m}{n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt\dfrac{n}{2}$$

Now, let us separate it into two cases.

---

**Case 1** : $n=2k$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

We have
$$0\lt \frac{m}{2n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt 2k$$
So, in this case, the larget $m$ is $m_{max}=2k-1$ for which the largest root of the form $\dfrac{m}{2n}\pi$ is given by $x_{max}=\dfrac{2k-1}{4k}\pi=\dfrac{6k-3}{12k}\pi$.

Similarly, we have
$$0\lt \frac{3m+2}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac{2}{3}\lt m\lt k-\frac 23\implies m_{max}=k-1\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-2}{12k}\pi$$
$$0\lt \frac{3m+1}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac 13\lt m\lt k-\frac 13\implies m_{max}=k-1\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-4}{12k}\pi$$
$$0\lt \frac{m}{n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt k\implies m_{max}=k-1\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-6}{12k}\pi$$

Therefore, when $n\ (=2k)$ is even, the largest root is
$$\max\bigg(\frac{6k-3}{12k}\pi,\frac{6k-2}{12k}\pi,\frac{6k-4}{12k}\pi,\frac{6k-6}{12k}\pi\bigg)=\frac{6k-2}{12k}\pi=\color{red}{\frac{3n-2}{6n}\pi}$$

---

**Case 2** : $n=2k-1$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

We have
$$0\lt \frac{m}{2n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt 2k-1\implies m_{max}=2k-2\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-6}{12k-6}\pi$$
$$0\lt \frac{3m+2}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac{2}{3}\lt m\lt k-\dfrac 76\implies m_{max}=k-2\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-8}{12k-6}\pi$$
$$0\lt \frac{3m+1}{3n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff -\frac 13\lt m\lt k-\frac 56\implies m_{max}=k-1\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-4}{12k-6}\pi$$
$$0\lt \frac{m}{n}\pi\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}\iff 0\lt m\lt k-\frac 12\implies m_{max}=k-1\implies x_{max}=\frac{6k-6}{12k-6}\pi$$

Therefore, when $n\ (=2k-1)$ is odd, the largest root is
$$\max\bigg(\frac{6k-6}{12k-6}\pi,\frac{6k-8}{12k-6}\pi,\frac{6k-4}{12k-6}\pi,\frac{6k-6}{12k-6}\pi\bigg)=\frac{6k-4}{12k-6}\pi=\color{red}{\frac{3n-1}{6n}\pi}$$